# Adding custom delimiters back to a csv?

Tags: python, csv

Currently, I take in a csv file using custom delimiters, "|". I then read it in and modify it using the code below:

```
import csv


ChangedDate = '2018-10-31'

firstfile  = open('example.csv',"r")
firstReader = csv.reader(firstfile, delimiter='|')
firstData = list(firstReader)
outputFile = open("output.csv","w")

iteration = 0

for row in firstData:
    firstData[iteration][25] = ChangedDate
    iteration+=1

outputwriter = csv.writer(open("output.csv","w"))

outputwriter.writerows(firstData)
outputFile.close()
```

However, when I write the rows to my output file, they are comma seperated. This is a problem because I am dealing with large financial data, and therefore commas appear naturally, such as $8,000.00, hence the "|" delimiters of the original file. Is there a way to "re-delimit" my list before I write it to an output file?

Comment: well `csv.writer(outputFile ,delimiter='|')` what's the issue?

Comment: note that you're opening the file twice for writing.

Comment: Please read [the CSV module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: python 3: `outputFile = open("output.csv","w",newline="")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the [delimiter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter) to the [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

```
with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
    outputwriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|')
```